# Check in database if no result, then add with node.js-mysql

Tags: node.js

When I parse a page, then I get a number of titles. Each title must be checked in database and if it is not added into database, then do it.

Example list:

```
test
test2
test3
test4
test2
test
test5
test4
```

As you see, there are some duplicates.

My code:

```
        var $ = cheerio.load(body);
        $(".program-table .item").each(function() {
            var titleOriginal = $(this).find(".title-original").text().match(/(.+)\s\
            var movieYear = titleOriginal[2];
            var movieTitle = titleOriginal[1];

            connection.query("SELECT id FROM movie WHERE name = ? AND year = ?", [movieTitle, movieYear], function(err, result) {
                if (err) return;

                if (result.length) {
                    console.log('Found, ID: %s', result[0].id);
                } else {
                    connection.query("INSERT INTO movie SET name = ?, year = ?", [movieTitle, movieYear], function(err, result) {
                        if (err) return;
                        console.log('Not found, adding into database. ID: %s', result.insertId);
                    });
                }
            });
        });
```

Result: When database is clean or non record containing titles, the script will add **all** title into database with duplicates. When I start it second time, the it will show me that record with title found and it will skip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.each()` is not waiting for the query to finish before moving on to the next element. You could use something like [async](https://github.com/caolan/async) to help manage this:

```
var async = require('async');

// ...

var $ = cheerio.load(body);
async.each($('.program-table .item'), function(el, cb) {
  var titleOriginal = $(el).find('.title-original').text().match(/(.+)\s/)
  var movieYear = titleOriginal[2];
  var movieTitle = titleOriginal[1];

  connection.query('SELECT id FROM movie WHERE name = ? AND year = ?',
                   [movieTitle, movieYear],
                   function(err, result) {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    if (result.length) {
      console.log('Found, ID: %s', result[0].id);
      cb();
    } else {
      connection.query('INSERT INTO movie SET name = ?, year = ?',
                       [movieTitle, movieYear],
                       function(err, result) {
        if (err) return cb(err);
        console.log('Not found, adding into database. ID: %s', result.insertId);
        cb();
      });
    }
  });
}, function(err) {
  // if `err` is set, we had a database query error ...
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

I wasn't sure what your `titleOriginal` regexp was supposed to be (it looks like it was cut off in your original code), so I guessed.